# How to modify a javascript function inside an iframe using bookmarklets?

Tags: javascript, iframe, bookmarklet

Lets say I have a html page with an iframe, which has its own javascript functions.

```
function foo(){
//doSomething
}
```

- The web browser is pointed to the
  main page.
- Both the main page and the iframe are
  in the same domain.

I can access/call those functions from the address bar.

```
javascript:document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.foo();
```

I can replace js functions in the main page by entering new function definitions inside the address bar.
However it doesn't work on functions inside the iframe.

```
javascript:function foo(){//doSomethingElse}
```

This only seems to add that function to the main page. The iframe still uses its own foo function.

I could open the iframe in a new tab, then it's possible to modify the function.
But I wonder if it's possible to replace js functions which are inside an iframe by entering them in the address bar from the main page?

Comment: Interesting question but... I'm just curious about the use of such a tweak. Why would you do that?

Comment: It can be useful when you would want to add/modify functionality to a webpage through bookmarklets, where you can reuse the existing javascript code without resorting to opening those frames in a seperate tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, it treats foo as a variable and assigns it as a function reference (or something like that... my javascript is not the greatest). The enclosing ()() is so that the returned value is ignored and the page does not reload.

```
javascript:(document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.foo=function(){alert('bar');})()
```

(tested in firefox)